# C# Open selected listview items using foreach

Tags: c#, listview, foreach

What should be in (???) 
I want to open for example 3 selected files in my simple file explorer

```
 private void Open_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (???) 
        {
            string ImageViewName = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@textBox1.Text.Remove(3, 1) + "/" + ImageViewName);
        }
    }
```

in textbox1 is my path to the files

Comment: *"open for example 3 selected files in my simple file explorer"* - `foreach(var file in mySimpleExplorerInstance.Files.Where(o => o.IsSelected).Take(3)) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each File is in a List called Files

```
foreach (File myFile in Files){
//Do something with myFile
}
```

The foreach block will iterate through each File in Files. The current selected file, which can be accessed from within the foreach block, is called 'myFile' in this instance.

I am new to stackoverflow so I'm open to advice about my answer too!